'User.Claims' object is empty when NET 6 app is deployed in Linux and returns error 401 after user login
I have a NET 6 app with Angular frontend. It works in a production environment set up with Windows Servers and IIS. However I have to migrate it to Linux cloud, due to costs and other reasons.
I've set up a mini cluster on my home lab where i deployed 2 Ubuntu 22.04 servers for web (using NGINX) and load balancing/failover, and one for the SQL server. On the emulated environment the code runs and the app works just fine.
I'm using Kamatera Cloud service (again, due to costs) where I have 4 VMs with Ubuntu 22.04, 2 for web, 1 for SQL and 1 for HaProxy.
Once the app is deployed, the system navigates to login screen, the user enters the credentials and  for whatever reason, then I receive a 401 error on the browser console.
the code snippet below is where the problem is located.
            try
            {
                bl.UserID = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                
                //other code here....

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }

The code above is when a request is done in the backend, so after some digging, I saw that, maybe, there is an issue with the authguard interceptor ? (Angular code below)
  private processRequestWithToken(token: string, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!!token && this.isSameOriginUrl(req)) {
      req = req.clone({        
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(() => {
      },
      error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (error.status !== 401) {
            return;
          }

          setTimeout(() => 
            notify('Unauthorized or user logged out. Please login again.', 'warning', 4000),
          3000);

          this.router.navigate(['/authentication/login']);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private isSameOriginUrl(req: any) {
    // It's an absolute url with the same origin.
    if (req.url.startsWith(`${window.location.origin}/`)) {
      return true;
    }

    // It's a protocol relative url with the same origin.
    // For example: //www.example.com/api/Products
    if (req.url.startsWith(`//${window.location.host}/`)) {
      return true;
    }

    // It's a relative url like /api/Products
    if (/^\/[^\/].*/.test(req.url)) {
      return true;
    }

    // It's an absolute or protocol relative url that
    // doesn't have the same origin.
    return false;
  }

no matter what I do I always get a 401 error. Can you please guide me on what should I check. I'll provide as much info as required.
The application (with no changes on the code) works fine on Windows with IIS and on a local Linux homelab. The Kamatera Cloud VMs are with Ubuntu Linux 22.04 and all the available updates installed.
Thank you in advance
I tried to forcefully pass the interceptor validation tried different methods of IndetityServer setup in Startup.cs file, even storing the key in the DbContext but with no luck. I was expecting for the user to be authenticated, but no luck

load balancer can be an issue when validating claims.  (different private keys)  I think you can configure the balancer to use "sticky sessions" for this.

It cloud also be some claims mapping problems,  see my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/

@browsermator the strange thing is that the same code deployed in Windows, works as it should, I'm able to login etc, its the Linux deployment that frustrates me and I try to find out what's going on. I already use "sticky sessions", Also in my homelab when deployed in Linux it works as well, I followed the instructions to the letter in order to deploy it to linux both in the homelab and on the cloud, yet I get different behavior
